# Задача на вещественные числа с эпсилионом

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа

[image: Вот сама задача]

вот мой код:

```
eps=1e-6
x,y,z= map(float, input().split())
p=0
n=int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
    a,b,c,q = map(float, input().split())
    x=x-a*q
    z=z - c * q
    y=y - b * q
if (x<=eps) and (y<=eps) and (z<=eps)<eps:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

программа выдает ошибку но я не понимаю почему также не очень понимаю что такое Q

Вот тестовый пример для копирования:

1.0 1.0 1.0

3

1 0 0 1

0 0.5 0 2

0 0 0.25 4

Comment: И где код? А также, где описание проблемы - в чём сложность-то?

Comment: @Сергей вот задача, не то загрузил

Comment: хух, а я уж испугался, увидев пример на 1 действие с делением :-)

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: @Сергей в начале написаны входные и выходные данные

Comment: И в целом неудачный код с точки зрения ввода. Надо хоть писать, ввод чего ожидается.

Comment: `and (z<=eps)<eps`

Comment: Ошибку уже нашел @TigerTV.ru, ну а Q - количество булочек, например, если булочка - один из продуктов. Всего продуктов N - 3 в нашем примере. Условно: булочки, масло, чай. А А,В,С - сколько ценного есть в одной булочке (в порции чая, в пачке масла). На будущее просьба тестовые примеры текстом помещать, а то вручную копировать пришлось.